# Making trivial GeoJSON file with Feature collection of points

Tags: geojson, point, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to generate a GeoJSON file with a feature collection of points to render in QGIS, however, when I load my `.geojson` file I don't see anything. To figure out what's going on, I've tried to get a trivial file to load. Here is an example:

```json
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-27.4670353, 153.013123]
      },
      "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
    }
  ]
}
```

According to [the GeoJSON documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-4);

> The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a
> geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
> System 1984 (WGS 84) datum, with longitude and latitude units of
> decimal degrees

Sure enough, when I put the coordinates `-27.4670353, 153.013123` into https://coordinates-converter.com/ I get a location somewhere in Brisbane, Australia:

[image]

However, when I copy the above JSON file into https://geojson.io/ I get nothing:

[image]

When I load the example GeoJSON file at https://gist.github.com/wavded/1200773?short_path=99c1af9 it does seem to work though:

[image]

However, to the best of my knowledge, these are not WGS84 decimal coordinates. What's happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you carefully look at GeoJSON docs that you cited, you can read

> using the World Geodetic System 1984 (WGS 84) datum, with **longitude**
> **and latitude** units of decimal degrees

It clearly states that order of coordinates is `[lon, lat]`, but in your GeoJSON order is reversed. So if you try this in geojson.io:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          153.013123,
          -27.4670353
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

you will see this:

[image]

Comment: I often find it a good starting point to create a GeoJSON using geojson.io .